# LINQ query compary multiple with multiple

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

**UPDATED: Apologies my colleague has updated the model a little**

**UPDATED: Given context to this idea perhaps itll help**

I have a list of ShowData for a Show. Each ShowData contains a number of Prints. So

***1 Show -> Many ShowData -> Many Prints***

I have two datasets both of the same type of object - ShowData

A Fingerprint looks like the following:

```
public class ShowData
{
    public ShowData() { }        
    public int time { get; set; }
    public List<Prints> prints { get; set; }
}
public class Prints
{
    public Prints() { }        
    public int value { get; set; }
    public string range { get; set; }
}
```

I get all the ShowData for a particular show:

```
var ShowData1 = (from showData1 in context.ShowDatas
                                where (showData1.Show.Id == 1)                                    
                                select new
                                {
                                    showData = showData1,
                                    prints = showData1.Prints
                                });
```

So an example is:

```
DATASET A

time      prints
1         {1,low},{4,low},{8,low},{9,low},{10,low},{11,high},{15,high},{16,high},{18,high}
2         {4,low},{7,low},{8,low},{9,low},{10,low},{12,high},{15,high},{16,high},{19,high}
3         {1,low},{2,low},{3,low},{8,low},{9,low},{11,high},{12,high},{15,high},{16,high}
4         {1,low},{7,low},{8,low},{9,low},{10,low},{11,high},{12,high},{14,high},{15,high}
5         {1,low},{5,low},{6,low},{8,low},{9,low},{11,high},{14,high},{17,high},{19,high}

DATASET B

time      prints
1         {1,low},{2,low},{3,low},{4,low},{5,low},{11,high},{12,high},{13,high},{18,high}
2         {0,low},{3,low},{5,low},{6,low},{7,low},{11,high},{13,high},{19,high},{20,high}
```

The first dataset (DATASET A) is roughly 4000 ShowData items long. I have another dataset of the ShowData, which is about 120 items long (DATASET B).

Im trying to find a way to compare the two lists to bring out all the **time** points where the prints in DATASET B **have at least 2 matches** to a print in DATASET A. **However there need to be at least 2 matches for low and 2 matches for high**

So my returned query might look like the following:

```
TimeInDataSetB         TimesInDataSetAForLows      TimeInDataSetAForHighs
1                              1,3,5                       3,4
2                                                           5
```

So above, the print (with range=low) at time 1 in DatasetB had at least 2 matches with prints located at times 1,3,5 in DatasetA AND the print (with range=high) at time 1 in DatasetB had at least 2 matches with prints located at times 3,4 in DatasetA.

Item at time 2 in DataSetB has no matches for any in DataSet for the lows and only 1 match for the highs

Can anyone help with that? (im looking for answer in c#)

**Using the method described in the first answer i tried the following:**

```
var query3 = from a in recordingPoints
                             from b1 in ShowData1
                             let timeIntersects = a.Prints.Intersect(b1.prints, printsEqualityComparer)
                             where timeIntersects.GroupBy(x => x.Range)
                                                 .All(x => x.Count() > 2)
                             group b1 by a.Time into grouped
                             select new
                             {

                                 TimeInDataSetA = grouped.Key,
                                 TimeInDataSetB = grouped.ToArray()
                             };
```

where recordingPoints is a list of ShowData

**DATASET TO TEST WITH**

```
List<ShowData> bigdataset = new List<Ent.ShowData>();
                List<ShowData> smalldataset = new List<Ent.ShowData>();

                List<int> ints = new List<int>(new int[]{1, 4, 8, 9, 10, 11, 15, 16, 18});
                ShowData od = new Ent.ShowData();
                od.Show.Id = 7;
                foreach (int it in ints)
                {
                    Prints pr = new Prints();
                    if (it < 11)
                        pr.Range = "low";
                    else
                        pr.Range = "high";
                    pr.Value = it.ToString();
                    od.Prints.Add(pr);
                }                    
                od.Time = 1;
                bigdataset.Add(od);

                ints = new List<int>(new int[] { 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 16, 19 });
                od = new Ent.ShowData();
                od.Show.Id = 7;
                foreach (int it in ints)
                {
                    Prints pr = new Prints();
                    if (it < 11)
                        pr.Range = "low";
                    else
                        pr.Range = "high";
                    pr.Value = it.ToString();
                    od.Prints.Add(pr);
                }
                od.Time = 2;
                bigdataset.Add(od);

                ints = new List<int>(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 11, 12, 15, 16 });
                od = new Ent.ShowData();
                od.Show.Id = 7;
                foreach (int it in ints)
                {
                    Prints pr = new Prints();
                    if (it < 11)
                        pr.Range = "low";
                    else
                        pr.Range = "high";
                    pr.Value = it.ToString();
                    od.Prints.Add(pr);
                }
                od.Time = 3;
                bigdataset.Add(od);

                ints = new List<int>(new int[] { 1, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15 });
                od = new Ent.ShowData();
                od.Show.Id = 7;
                foreach (int it in ints)
                {
                    Prints pr = new Prints();
                    if (it < 11)
                        pr.Range = "low";
                    else
                        pr.Range = "high";
                    pr.Value = it.ToString();
                    od.Prints.Add(pr);
                }
                od.Time = 4;
                bigdataset.Add(od);

                ints = new List<int>(new int[] { 1, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11, 14, 17, 19 });
                od = new Ent.ShowData();
                od.Show.Id = 7;
                foreach (int it in ints)
                {
                    Prints pr = new Prints();
                    if (it < 11)
                        pr.Range = "low";
                    else
                        pr.Range = "high";
                    pr.Value = it.ToString();
                    od.Prints.Add(pr);
                }
                od.Time = 5;
                bigdataset.Add(od);

                ints = new List<int>(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 11, 12, 13, 18 });
                od = new Ent.ShowData();
                foreach (int it in ints)
                {
                    Prints pr = new Prints();
                    if (it < 11)
                        pr.Range = "low";
                    else
                        pr.Range = "high";
                    pr.Value = it.ToString();
                    od.Prints.Add(pr);
                }
                od.Time = 1;
                smalldataset.Add(od);

                ints = new List<int>(new int[] { 0, 3, 5, 6, 7, 11, 13, 19, 20 });
                od = new Ent.ShowData();
                foreach (int it in ints)
                {
                    Prints pr = new Prints();
                    if (it < 11)
                        pr.Range = "low";
                    else
                        pr.Range = "high";
                    pr.Value = it.ToString();
                    od.Prints.Add(pr);
                }
                od.Time = 2;
                smalldataset.Add(od);

var printsEqualityComparer = new PrintsEqualityComparer();

                    var query4 = from a in smalldataset
                                 from b1 in bigdataset
                                 let timeIntersects = a.Prints.Intersect(b1.Prints, printsEqualityComparer)
                                 where timeIntersects.GroupBy(x => x.Range)
                                                     .All(x => x.Count() > 1)
                                 group b1 by a.Time into grouped
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     TimeInDataSetA = grouped.Key,
                                     TimeInDataSetB = grouped.ToArray()
                                 };
```

Comment: Are you sure you provided the right sample data? There's no time 0 in data set A and there's no time > 3 in set B...

Comment: He said there were 4000 in set A and 120 in set B but truncated the list to save space.

Comment: yep i just truncated it! sorry bit confusing

Answer (score 3):

You can perform an intersect for each item in B over each item in A filtering on a minimum match of 3 and grouping by the Time set in A like:

```
var query = from a in listA
            from b in listB
            where a.prints.Intersect(b.prints).Count() >= 3
            group b by a.time into grouped
            select new
            {
                TimeInDataSetA = grouped.Key,
                TimeInDataSetB = grouped.ToArray()
            };
```

Edit, based on your new request, you can provide a equalityComparer to the intersect method to determine equality for 2 instances of Prints. Note that in the example below i provided a very primitive implementation. Please read the link provided.

```
// please see: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx
class PrintsEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Prints>
{
    public bool Equals(Prints x, Prints y)
    {
        return object.Equals(x, y) && object.Equals(x.value, y.value);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Prints obj)
    {
        return obj.range.GetHashCode() ^ obj.value.GetHashCode();
    }
}
var printsEqualityComparer = new PrintsEqualityComparer();

var query = from a in listA
        from b in listB
        let timeIntersects = a.prints.Intersect(b.prints, printsEqualityComparer)
        where timeIntersects.GroupBy(x => x.range)
                            .All(x => x.Count() > 2)
        group b by a.time into grouped
        select new
        {
            TimeInDataSetA = grouped.Key,
            TimeInDataSetB = grouped.ToArray()
        };
```

Comment: this sounds like a very dumb question, but when creating the PrintsEqualityComparer, does it use the Equals method we create when comparing the two Prints to get the intersect? as in if there are other properties on Prints, but we're just comparing range and value, then we do return object.Equals(x.Range, y.Range) && object.Equals(x.Value, y.Value). Will it just compare those two properties?

Comment: Hi Polity, unfortunately this is not working... it seems to just return all the FingerPrints in Dataset B for every one of Dataset A

Comment: Intersect internally uses a lightweight HashSet implementation in order to find the items in both collections. For performance reasons, it uses the GetHashCode method to estimate objects with  a potential equality and the equal method to actually determine the equality. Now i suspect that my given implementation of the Equals method is incorrect. Removing the object.Equals(x, y) part of the expression should fix the problem since the object will very likely never be equal (checks on reference rather than state).

Comment: ok so i apologise, it works partly. i created some datasets in code from the above and got 1,3 for datasetA[1] and 5 for datasetA[2]. it missed number 4 for dataset[1] for some reason

Comment: Can you post a concrete data set which i can test?

Comment: Is it possible with a nested select?

Comment: It's also possible with a nested select although performance will be likely lower and you will probably run into the same problem. I havent had time to test your code but again, i suspect the problem lies in the EqualityComparer implementation. Try a differnt implementation for equals

Comment: if there is a slightly lower performance one, could you post it? i tried `public bool Equals(Prints x, Prints y)
        {
            return (x.Value == y.Value && x.Range==y.Range);            
        } ` but didnt work. how much does the hashcode have to do with it?

Comment: That seems to be a correct implementation. If you post your class definitions or even better your entire test code, i can easily check it after dinner

Comment: Thank you so much. i'd love to compensate you for your time if possible, check my profile to contact me (through my website). ive added all the test code. any chance we could return the three arrays as described above: `TimeInDataSetB         TimesInDataSetAForLows      TimeInDataSetAForHighs` with just the times?

Comment: please contact me through my contact form and i can send you a testproject

Comment: I did actually, yesterday evening. I will try again, else you can contact me at koen[at]lockpickers.nl